# For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook

Tags: debugging, excel, foreach, runtime-error, vba

I'm very new to VBA and trying to debug the following code. I keep getting --> "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch". When I debug, the line "For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets" is highlighted in yellow. I'm just trying to create a message box that gives me a list of the names of all the worksheets in a workbook. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub ListStates()
Dim ws As Worksheets
Dim message As String
message = "Here is a list of states:"
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    message = message & vbCrLf & "ws.Name"
Next
MsgBox message, vbInformation, "State list"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
Dim ws As Worksheets
```

to

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
```

The Worksheets object is a collection of Worksheet objects. And you are trying to loop though each `Worksheet` in `Worksheets`

Answer (score 0):

And in addition, remove the quotes bracketing ws.Name - line should be:

```
message = message & vbCrLf & ws.Name
```